# Using autonumber in a sharepoint document library

Tags: 2013, document-library

I am creating a document for SharePoint and need it published to a SharePoint Document library and not a list, because of some functionality within the document.

I want to set an auto reference using a workflow, so have created a read-only field, but can not find a way to set the field automatically.  I want the format of the field to be "abcra-001". so im assuming that I need to use concat somewhere along the lines.

Please help, its driving me crazy, because I have done this on list library's before.

Comment: What is abcra and what is 001?

Comment: sorry that is simply just the format I would like to use, a few letters then an "ID" style number following this

Comment: You can create a text field and fill the value on the workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually do this in the following way:

- Create a new list called counter
- Create a number column in the counter list
- Create a workflow on your main list which gets the value from the counter list, add 1 and write it back to the counter list

This approach will allow you to create multiple counters if your client want one counter per document category for example. Just add one more column in the counter list that you can use for reference.